# Writing NPM modules: install dependencies globally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, jslint, jshint

*Summary: is there a way to list a dependency for your to-be-published npm module as global?*

I'm currently authoring an [npm module](https://npmjs.org/package/jshinter) which relies on [JSHINT](https://npmjs.org/package/jshint) as a main dependency. The idea for my module is to be able to call JSHINT programmatically from Node. I do this by using `fs.exec` on the jshint command.

The problem, however, is that unless the JSHINT is installed globally (`npm -g install jshint`), when executing the jshint command (even from the command line), I get:

`-bash: jshint: command not found`

I've looked around and can't seem to find a solution. What I've [found so far](http://www.bwigg.com/2012/10/npm-jshint-command-not-found/) hasn't worked.

I was wondering, then, when authoring an NPM package to be published, is there a way to list one of the dependencies as a global dependency which must be installed with `-g` by npm when users install my module?

Comment: @hexacyanide Thanks, that answers it. Is there a way to close this question?

Comment: You can delete it, or you can wait for it to be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: If you are relying on the `jshint` module, why are you using the command line command instead of loading the module and calling it directly? Then you avoid this whole problem.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I don't believe it's meant to be used that way. The JSHint module exposes a single JSHINT function, but it is undocumented (as far as I can tell) and it's unclear to me what it does due to badly named, single-letter variable names. That was the first thing I tried though, and I'm sure that it could work with a lot more work on my end. I had to go with this "simpler" solution because I need to continue working on other parts of the project I am working on.